# How to define a subdocument in SimpleSchema Meteor with an autovalue without inserting it on each parent document insert?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm trying to define a schema for a collection with a sub document, both parent and sub documents have autovalue fields that should get set on inserts.
The problem is that when I try to insert a new parent document (without any sub documents) I get an error stating that the sub-document fields are required.

Here is the full code to reproduce the problem:

main.js

```
ChatRooms = new Meteor.Collection("chatRooms");

schema_ChatRooms_ChatMesssage = new SimpleSchema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        label: "User ID",
        autoValue: function() {
            if (this.isInsert) {
              if (! this.isFromTrustedCode) {
                return this.userId;
              }
            } else {
              this.unset();
            }},
        autoform: { omit: true }
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        label: "Content",
        max: 1000,
        min: 1
    },
    creationDate: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Created On",
        autoValue: function() {
            if (!this.isSet) {
                return new Date();
            }
            else {
              this.unset();
            }},
        autoform: { omit: true }
    }
});

schema_ChatRoom = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name",
        max: 50,
        min: 1
    },
    isPublic: {
        type: Boolean,
        label: "Public"
    },
    creationDate: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Created On",
        autoValue: function() {
            if (!this.isSet) {
                return new Date();
            }
            else {
              this.unset();
            }},
        autoform: { omit: true }
    },
    // Sub Documents
    chatMessages: {
        type: schema_ChatRooms_ChatMesssage,
        label: "Chat Messages",
        optional: true,
        autoform: { omit: true }
    }
});

ChatRooms.attachSchema(schema_ChatRoom);

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    AutoForm.addHooks(null, {
        onError: function(operation, error, template) {
                    alert(operation.toString() + " : " + error.toString());
                }
    });
}
```

main.html

```
<head>
  <title>TestSubDoc</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Create</h1>

  {{> quickForm collection="ChatRooms" id="chatRooms_create_form" type="insert"}}
</body>
```

I've tried adding an "optional: true" to "chatMessages" but it didn't solve it.
It seems like even when a sub-document is not included the sub-document autovalue still gets executed and creates a new subdocument with the generated values.

What can I do to properly create a document with sub-documents that have auto values?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to make all fields from schema_ChatRooms_ChatMesssage optional and ommited by autoform.